# Symfony / Doctrine double entry

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, double

I have a problem with my code and I don't understand what's the problem. That's my code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/{key}/warn/{sender}/{player}/{reason}")
 */
public function warnAction(Request $request, $key, $sender, $player, $reason)
{
    if($key == API::KEY) {
        $date = new \DateTime();
        $until = new \DateTime();
        $until->add(new \DateInterval("P" . ($reason * 3) . "D"));
        $type = $this->getBanType($reason);

        $ban = new Ban();
        $ban->setType($type);
        $ban->setSender($sender);
        $ban->setPlayer($player);
        $ban->setReason($reason);
        $ban->setDate($date);
        $ban->setUntil($until);
        $ban->setNotes("");

        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $manager->persist($ban);
        $manager->flush();

        $data = array(
            "status" => "success",
            "id" => $ban->getId()
        );

        return new JsonResponse($data);
    } else {
        $data = array(
            "status" => "failed"
        );

        return new JsonResponse($data);
    }
}

/**
 * @param $reason
 * @return int
 */
public function getBanType($reason)
{
    if($reason <= 2) {
        return Type::MUTE;
    } else {
        return Type::BAN;
    }
}
```

Now, when I run /api/mykey/warn/someone/someone/1, everything works and it's written into the MySQL database. Now I delete it.

[image]

But when I run /api/mykey/warn/someone/someone/4, there are two entries written into the DB. Why is that, and how can I change the code that it's only written one time into the DB?

[image]

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Check your browser's devtools to see if there are two get requests being sent.

Comment: i would guess you are using browser for testing, and the browser just refreshes the window with former test and thus making request and inserting your entry into database. also, you can see in log file if you get 2 HTTP requests (which i'm sure you do)